# Running sudo when user has blank password?

Tags: terminal, user-account, sudo

I have a user with a blank password, but now I can't run `sudo` with that account.

```
sudo ls
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't change the password to do this and then change it back?

Comment: Genius! Can’t ssh into a computer if the password is NULL either afaik. Same with emoji in the password, if you can’t type it, you can’t use it to authenticate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo` on macOS requires the account to have a password:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202035

Therefore it is not possible to just press ENTER to continue at the prompt, like you would expect from some other systems.

This behaviour is enforced through a configuration of the PAM subsystem. You can change the settings for that in `/etc/pam.d`, where you have a `sudo` file that setups the authentication requirements for the `sudo` command.

WARNING: Changing the contents of the files in `/etc/pam.d` incorrectly can deny you from logging to your system at all. Only make changes if you know what you're doing, you have a backup - and you feel confident in booting in Recovery mode to undo your changes if it should fail.

Comment: How would I configure `/etc/pam.d/sudo` to allow user with empty password to use sudo?